# Should i change the DB_HOST to 127.0.0.1 on servers database.php file?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

So I'm using XAMPP and Laravel 5.x with PHP 7.4, I encountered an error when loading up my local server where it wasn't able to access my database on my system. When I searched online the answer I found said to change my local `DB_HOST` address to `127.0.0.1` in the `database.php` file instead of setting it to localhost because MYSQL would use TCP instead of a UNIX socket for its connection. If I push this change to the staging or live server would this cause an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the live server, you will need to connect to the DB server that will contain the DB that is used by the application,
so the configs at `.env` that relate to DB need to be changed with the live DB server

```
DB_HOST=[HERE DB SERVER IP]
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=[database name]
DB_USERNAME=[user name]
DB_PASSWORD= [user password]
```

you need to read about [Laravel Project Deployment](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment)

Comment: Thanks for your answer i read up on it. i was just double checking.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel utilizes the DotEnv library to configure different environments.
[You can follow the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration) on how to generate an `.env` file for each environment (local and dev server).

Comment: Thanks for the answer now i get the whole why you put .env file in the git ignore file, so you don't mess with the serves .env file and mess the connections already set

Answer (score -1):

You must enter actual URL of database.

If it's accessible via localhost on dev server, then it's fine. Otherwise put actual URL.

---

`localhost` is alias to IP `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Within the scope of MySQL `localhost` is _not_ an alias to `127.0.0.1`. Using `localhost` will cause any MySQL client [using the official MySQL driver/client reference implementation] to attempt to use the Unix socket, and fail if it is not available. Using `127.0.0.1` will make MySQL use TCP.

Comment: @Sammitch Right thats what i read online, the UNIX socket messing with the connection on the local system and to alter it use the 127.0.0.1 for TCP. Its working locally. Should i just enable the UNIX socket somehow? or since its working keep it as is?

Answer (score -1):

no Don't do it

localhost is IP of your PC

use other host as Live(production) server